# Removing elements from array based on second array

Tags: perl

I have a list of filenames prefixes in an array `@list1` and a list of full filenames in a second array `@list2`. In the end I want to end up with a third array containing only full filenames that do not match the prefixes in `@list1`. I've started with:

```
for my $match (@list1) {
  @list3 = grep { !/$match/ } @list2;
}
```

but it doesn't do what I thought it would do. What options do i have to get the result I'm looking for.

Comment: foreach my $match (@list1) { ... } for a start. This isn't PHP, mate.

Comment: @hd1, Are you saying he should use "`foreach`" instead of "`for`"? If so, that's completely wrong. The two keywords are 100% equivalent. I never use "`foreach`", for example.

Comment: no they are not equivalent. foreach my $element (@array) walks @array, assigning every element therein to $element. On the other hand, for assigns integers to the loop variable.

Comment: @hd1 Lets ask the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops). And it states: *“The `foreach` keyword is actually a synonym for the `for` keyword, so you can use either.”* The *behaviour* of such a loop is characterized as C-style-for or as a foreach iterator, but in Perl **the keywords are equivalent**. Try it out if you don't believe me. Also, your notion about integers is totally wrong: `foreach (my ($s, $o)=("", SomeClass->new); length $s < 10; do{$s .= "x"; $o->method}) {...}` is valid, but uses two loop variables and strings and objects.

Comment: Apologies, must be used to an older version of perl, where this isn't the case, or not recognising TIMTOWTDI

Comment: hd1: I can't speak to Perl4 (from the mid-90's), but Perl5's "for" and "foreach" have always been synonymous.  Perl5 has been out since around 1994-1995.  Are you talking about versions more than 15 years old?

Comment: Am I the only one who notices that this problem (processing a list and using a second one, sometimes a file of "stopwords", to filter it) was asked frequently here in the last days?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps an alternation regex will help:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @list1 = qw/a.f c data g j/;
my @list2 = qw/myfile.txt a.file.txt data.txt otherfile.txt jargon.txt/;

my $regex = join '|', map "\Q$_\E", @list1;

my @list3 = grep !/^(?:$regex)/, @list2;

print "$_\n" for @list3;
```

Output:

```
myfile.txt
otherfile.txt
```

Comment: This is a really elegant and efficient solution , as long as `@list1` isn't too big. Probably couldn't have been solved better.

Comment: @amon - Thank you.  I greatly appreciate your comment.

Comment: Note 2 issues: 1) \Q and \E threated as escaped characters for `""`. 2) Your $regex will be compiled @list2 times. Use /o modifier to avoid this issue. But, this makes snippet of code not re-usable with other @list1

Comment: @PSIAlt - Good catch on the $regex compiling issue. Thank you. Used `/o` to avoid this. Am unclear about issue 1.

Comment: @Kenosis Tnx for the benchmark, seems my answ was not good as i supposed, so i deleted it. Issue 1 was my bad, too (\Q\E works in string literals - wow). Your variant is most speedy, but there is drawback - if you put this code into a function, when you call with different `@list1` its actually wont change in regex. This can be fixed with **qr** variant (theGrepQR variant in your [benchmark](http://pastebin.com/3c6VpqvZ) )

Comment: @PSIAlt - I appreciated your answer and I'm sorry you deleted it.  Cleaver, it was..  You're quite correct that the `/o` modifier freezes the regex for the life of the script, so a drawback if different lists needed to be used.  Thank you, again, for your comments, as they are valuable.

Comment: Settled on using `qr` to avoid regex recompilation while `grep`ping, as the `/o` switch--although faster (see [benchmark](http://pastebin.com/3c6VpqvZ))--freezes the regex for the script's life.

Comment: @Kenosis I cannot explain why your run for `/o` faster. On my run same test code "theGrepQR" function is 34% faster than "theGrepOModifier". Explaination is simple: `qr//` will compile outside test timings so its already precompiled when test runs.

Comment: @Kenosis Thank you was exactly what i was looking for, Thank you to PSIAlt for the assist as well

Comment: @h3r2on - I removed the `qr//` as it's actually slower using it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a more list-expression-like way (as in your example), you could work with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util 'first';
use feature 'say';

my @filenames = qw(foo bar baz quux alice bob);
my @forbidden = qw(f ba);

my @matching  = grep {
    my $filename = $_;
    not defined first { $filename =~ /^\Q$_/ } @forbidden;
} @filenames;

say for @matching;
```

Output:

```
quux
alice
bob
```

**Note**: I used `first` here instead of the core-`grep` because with long `@forbidden` lists it could be more efficient since it stops after the first (and possibly only) match.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @prefixes = qw(a b d);
my @items = qw(apple banana cow dog fruitcake orangutan crabcake deer);

my @nonmatching;
ITEMS: foreach my $item (@items) {
    foreach my $prefix (@prefixes) {
        next ITEMS if ($item =~ /^$prefix/)
    }
    push @nonmatching, $item
}

$,=$\="\n";
print @nonmatching;
```

yields

```
cow
fruitcake
orangutan
crabcake
```

Edited as per raina77ow's suggestions.

Comment: **-1**: You don't `use strict; use warnings`. But you should. You should declare *all* your variables, not only loop variables. You don't need to quote each element in the arrays, please take a shortcut with `qw()`. Messing with `$,` is ugly in most cases, `say foreach @nonmatching` is better readable. You don't need the `$matches` flag – just label the outer loop and do a `next ITEM` inside the `if`.

Comment: I will point out that strict, warnings, and no qw() are not *wrong*, but they're not accepted contemporary style. I would join(@nonmatching, "\n") rather than fiddle with $, - agreed; and ext ITEM is a little nicer - but also, not technically wrong either.

Comment: Although there are some old-fashioned or hackish practices here, from a structural viewpoint this is almost the same solution I came up with after reading the question. It's a very flexible, straightforward and very good readable solution IMO. So if @WinnieNicklaus used lexical variables and replaced the implicit array interpolation to a good readable `join` expression or maybe something like `say for @nonmatching`, I would absolutely upvote.

Comment: Okay, okay, I'll edit for style.  My purpose wasn't to show production-worthy code, it was to quickly show the OP one logic to solve the problem.  I couldn't remember the syntax for labeling loops since I so rarely have need for it, so I didn't bother with it. I should have, to get a nicer looking solution.  I respectfully disagree, however, about the use of `$,`.  I would rather maintain `@nonmatching` conceptually as a list (so `join` is out -- why am I creating a scalar? What does it mean?). Manipulating `$,` is a quick and easy way to format how your printed list will appear.

Comment: As for `say`, again this seems quite a pedantic distinction.  And by quickly manipulating $\, I don't need to bother with `use feature qw(say)`.  It's perfectly readable to anyone who knows what $\ is, and I for one learned about $\ long before I learned about `say`.